# Full Width Footer Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a full width footer in my site but can't get this to work. Here is the print:

http://i60.tinypic.com/s6kpwn.gif

I'm 90% sure that is some problem with my knowledge of bootstrap. Sorry. I've looked at some similar questions but it's different the elements they use.

Here is the site: http://bloganacastro.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your footer is in your container div so the full width is the width of your container. you should move the `<?php get_footer(); ?>` after your container closing div tag

Comment: I'll try that and come back here to reply. Thanks til now